# How to auto start web services when starting an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: apache, web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I set the [httpd](/questions/tagged/httpd) and [mysqld](/questions/tagged/mysqld) services to start automatically upon booting an [amazon-ec2](/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) instance?

Currently I have to start them manually by connecting to the instance via ssh and running `sudo service httpd start` and `sudo service mysqld start`.

Comment: and same for  codedeploy-agent :)

Answer (score 98):

Rather than starting over with a new AMI, you could just issue the following commands on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance...

```
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

You can check the settings before & after enabling these services to start on boot using the following commands...

```
sudo chkconfig --list mysqld
sudo chkconfig --list httpd
```

See all services using just...

```
sudo chkconfig --list
```

*NOTE*: *If you are having any trouble with chkconfig being in root's path, you can try specifying the full path like this...*

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
sudo /sbin/chkconfig httpd on
```

Comment: was worried sqld was getting shut down due to being out of memory but after adding a swap file it was still not starting up. Tuns out I just didn't have the service enabled. Duhhh. Thanks so much! works like a charm

Comment: +1 Still totally relevant/required, although I'd suggest checking settings first and before attempting to enable services - just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Even, better `sudo systemctl disable <name>` for Amazon Linnux 2, as mentioned in the reply by @yoshinorin

Answer (score 40):

It is different between Amazon Linux 1 and Amazon Linux 2.

#### Amazon Linux 1

In AmazonLinux1, use `chkconfig` command.

```sh
$ sudo chkconfig mysqld on
$ sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

#### Amazon Linux2

In AmazonLinux2, systemd was introduced. So, `chkconfig` is legacy command. You should use `systemctl`. It is a control command for systemd.

```sh
$ sudo systemctl enable mysqld
$ sudo systemctl enable httpd
```

You can confirm it is enabled or not using by `is-enabled` command.

```sh
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled mysqld
enabled
```

`chkconfig` command request will be forwarded to `systemctl`.

```sh
$ chkconfig mysqld on
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable mysqld.service'.
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell from the EC2 instance types list which flavour of Linux (1 or 2) they have?

Comment: @Jontia `cat /etc/os-release` if VERSION_ID is 2018.03 is 1.

Answer (score 7):

If you using **Amazon Linux 2 AMI** you need to follow these steps:

1. In AMI2 they are using `systemctl` for managing services check if it is installed on your machine
   2.`systemctl list-units --type=service` by this command check if tomcat.service is listed
2. `sudo systemctl enable tomcat.service` To eanable tomcat start on boot up
3. `systemctl is-enabled tomcat.service` To check if tomcat enabled to start on boot up linux system

After that you can reboot your linux system and tomcat will be started.

For more about `systemctl` [Click Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Answer (score 3):

One of my client wants to do this task and I have successfully done by using following way.

Following commands starts the services automatic when instance started.

**Auto start apache/httpd**

```
1) systemctl enable httpd
```

**Auto start redis service**

```
2) systemctl enable redis
```

**I have set SELINUX set to disabled in**

```
3) /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

**For mysql services**

```
sudo chkconfig mysqld on
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

Comment: Could you explain what each command mean? Example. What is systemctl , chkconfig etc.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem, here is the solution i am suggesting,
you need to create a file under /etc/init.d directory, e.g with name tomcat, and change the JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME parameters as per your system installation.
Once you do setup this file then run the below command:

```
sudo chkconfig <file-name> on
```

where  is the file you have created in /etc/init.d it is tomcat in my case.

```
[ec2-user@ip-<myip> init.d]$ cat tomcat
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.96
export $JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.96

case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
stop)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;;
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
chmod 755 tomcat
chkconfig --add tomcat
chkconfig --level 234 tomcat on
chkconfig --list tomcat
service tomcat start
```

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS on Amazon Linux2 process:
Installing ReactJS on EC2 and running the app at boot:

1. Once you connect to EC2 instance install NodeJS. Follow this tutorial:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html
2. Install httpd server using this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html
3. I used Git Clone to clone the ReactJS app on to /home/ec2-user.
4. Install Yarn using the command “npm install yarn -g”
5. Execute the following commands in the cloned project: “Yarn” and then “Yarn build”
6. Now Copy the build folder using : cp -a /build/. /var/www/html/
7. Now go to the /var/www/html/ here create a .htaccess file using vi and include the following content:  “Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]”
   Save the file with :wq
8. Now in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf search for Directory with “/var/www/html” attribute and change “AllowOverride None” to “AllowOverride All”. Now open the browser and enter http://ec2-ip or http://ec2-url you will see the default page
9. Enter the command “systemctl enable httpd” and then “systemctl start httpd” on AmazonLinux2. Now you can access the app on boot rather than running the app again and again.
   You are complete.

Answer (score 0):

The best way on Amazon Linux 2 is to use the following bash script on creation. This will install the updates, start Apache2, make it listed as a service so that it automatically restarts upon reboot, and the creation of an index.html and health.html sample files. Configuring a health page is important for application loadbalancers and for autoscaling groups.

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y

yum install httpd -y httpd-tools mod_ssl

service httpd start

chkconfig httpd on

systemctl start httpd

systemctl enable httpd

echo "Hello, World, from your Webserver on Amazon Linux" > /var/www/html/index.html

echo "Healthy" > /var/www/html/health.html
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -6):

Either use any of the preexisting LAMP AMI, it will have both of them running as service already.

One example is [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack#cloudImage), you will find several other when you fire an ec2 instance.

Comment: The user was specifically asking how to do this on a blank AMI not how to start up a pre-built AMI.